# android realm how to migrate

Tags: android, realm

I am developing android app with realm.
After I added new column to the model, error is called.

here is an error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tomoya.spoito, PID: 3007
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MapsActivity}: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: RealmMigration must be provided
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Read this: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to provide a migration to Realm though, basically you should provide your migration object to `RealmConfig.Builder`.

See sample project of migration for details.

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/MigrationExampleActivity.java#L79